# Hazing the new guy

Tags: reverse-puzzling

> Congratulations on your new job with us!
>
> You will be working with Alice on writing down details about `REDACTED`, the show that has those puzzles.
>
> Sincerely,
>   Mrs. Boss-Mann

On your first day, you were expecting to be told everything you would be dong in detail.  Turns out Alice enjoys hazing new people.  She hands you a piece of paper and, before walking away, tells you:

> I wrote down some details from the last episode.  You need to type in how their turns went and save that into the folder for the show.  Someone as smart as you should be able to figure this out.

Hoping the paper holds some much needed details, you unfold it.  Unfortunately, here's not much written on it, but you think you can make this work.

> New York Yankees (Proper Name)
>   1: 1150 - 2/3 - 0/4 - 3/7
>   2: 1700 - 3/3 - 1/4 - 3/7
>   3: 1850 - 3/3 - 3/4 - 5/7 *

**How did each player get their score and what is the name of the game?**

Comment: Is that * intentional??

Comment: @Sid yes (and 7 more for length requirement)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My guess is that the name of the game is

> Wheel of Fortune

The slip of paper represents

> A single round of the game. 
>  The answer of the puzzle is **New York Yankees** and the clue is **Proper Name** 
>  The numbers represent, from left to right, the players score (in dollars), the number of letters revealed in the first word, the second word and the third word. 
>  So, if the first player guessed **N** followed by **E** (which would require buying a vowel), then they would have revealed 2/3 letters of the first word, 0/4 letters of the second and 3/7 of the third.

Further notes

> A possible sequence of guesses (including the amounts won on each spin) following this logic could be 
>  **Player 1** 
>  **N - \$700** 
>  **E - \$700** (P1 loses \$250 for buying a vowel). 
>  **B** (play then passes to the next player for an incorrect guess). 
>  The board reads NE_ ____ __N_EE_  (2/3, 0/4, 3/7) 
>  **Player 2** 
>  **W - \$900** 
>  **R - \$800** 
>  **C** (play then passes to player 3). 
>  The board now reads NEW __R_ __N_EE_ (3/3, 1/4, 3/7) 
>  **Player 3** 
>  **Y - \$700** 
>  **S - \$700** 
>  **O - \$700** (P3 loses \$250 for buying a vowel). 
>  The board  now reads NEW YOR_ Y_N_EES (3/3, 3/4, 5/7) 
>  Player 3 then guesses correctly winning the round (hence the asterisk)

Comment: Correct game and logic.  I was also hoping to get the breakdown on how each got their exact score.  [This should help](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/be/Wheel_of_Fortune_Round_1_template_Season_31.png).

Comment: Ah, yes, okay I can add that in. It seems like I'll have to edit the last one a bit to make the scores work.